# jQuery AJAX shown form validation errors

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I got problem with shown validation error on below script, for example what I tested, I enter a correct email and wrong password, the request will returned both `Wrong email address` and `Wrong password` under each `input textbox`, it is not only `Wrong Password` is expected to shown, I tried hardcode required data in `request.php` and run this script directly, for either giving wrong data in in $_POST, the console response `{"error":{"lemail":"Wrong email address","lpassword":"Wrong password"}}`, can someone please have a look in my code what's goes wrong?

form with AJAX call:

```
<body>

<form role="form" method="post" id="login_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="lemail" name="lemail" placeholder="Your email"><span class="error" id="lemail_error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lpassword" name="lpassword" placeholder="Password"><span class="error" id="lpassword_error"></span>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_login" data-loading-text="Loading...">Sign In</button>
</div>
</form>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btn_login').click(function(){
        var parameters = $('#login_form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/callback/request.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'parameters' : parameters},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){

                if(response.success == 'logged'){
                    $('#login_form')[0].reset();
                    alert(response.success);

                }else if(response.inactivate == 'inactive'){
                    alert('Your account is inactive!');

                }else{
                    $('[id$="_error"]').html(''); //clear valid error msg

                    // display invalid error msg
                    $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
                        if(value){
                            $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        });
    });

});
</body>
```

request.php

```
parse_str($_POST['parameters'], $output);

$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($output['lemail'])));
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($output['lpassword']));

$func = new Functions();
$message = array();

//validate user's email and password from database
$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_email='".$email."' AND user_password='".sha1(sha1($password))."'") or die($mysqli->error);
$rows = $check->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$num = $check->num_rows;

$uId = $rows['user_id'];
$uEmail = $rows['user_email'];
$uPwd = $rows['user_password'];
$uType = $rows['account_type'];
$uStatus = $rows['account_status'];

// validate user's account
if(empty($email) || $email !== $uEmail){
    $message['error']['lemail']  = 'Wrong email address';
}
if(empty($password) || sha1(sha1($password)) !== $uPwd){
    $message['error']['lpassword'] = 'Wrong password';
}

if(!isset($message['error'])){

    if($uStatus == 0){
        $message['inactivate'] = 'inactive';

    }else{

        $message['success'] = 'logged';
    }
}

echo json_encode($message);
```

**Edited:**

Solved! nothing went wrong, just out of logic on variables comparison!! ;P

Comment: **Quote OP: *"Solved! nothing went wrong"*** ~ Then please post the answer below or delete the whole thing.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting string not array, you need to use parse_str function first.

Remove this enctype="multipart/form-data" from form

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="login_form">
```

Replace your data: line with this

```
data: {'parameters' : parameters},
```

After add this to your PHP

```
parse_str($_POST['parameters'], $output);

$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($output['lemail'])));
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($output['lpassword']));
```

Comment: can I have more details?

Comment: still not working...I wonder why the same script and method I use in register form is works brilliant.

Comment: Okay, so i debug it. Problem was in $_POST['parameters'], i forget for ' in array key, try now.

Comment: do it need to declare `$output=array();` ?

Comment: No, check now, edited. You need remove multipart from your form attributes, it is only if you are posting files

Answer (score 0):

in you php code first you have to deserliazed ur code.. put these lines at top..

```
$searcharray = array();
parse_str($_POST[parameters], $searcharray);


$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($searcharray['lemail'])));
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($searcharray['lpassword']));
```

Comment: actually the same script is working in my register form perfectly, I have no idea why its not work in login form.

Comment: but this is the way to get the values of form is u post them in a `serialized form`

Comment: the above script mean the code u pasted will work in register may be because there you may not using the ajax to post the form.. but its sure if you post the form in `serialized` form then u have to `deserialize` them first then only u can excess the form values..

Comment: both form are using ajax, but this login i have no idea, I tried tested it stand alone without others library loaded, but still same behaviour appear...i have been few hours working on this!!